# Accessing Array through for loop in Linux Shell script

Tags: arrays, linux, shell

I have the following shell script.
The problem I am facing is that in the first iteration ${NUM[${i}]} returns the whole content of the array and every following iteration returns empty.
Why is that so?

```
NUM="2 2 2 0"
i=0
    for CLIENT in ${BAG_CLIENTS} ; do
        if [ "$BFT" = true ]; then
          SERVERS="-$i"
        fi
        echo "Starting ${NUM[${i}]} clients with $PERCWRITES writes and $SERVERS serv$
        ssh rneiheiser@$CLIENT "~/runclient.sh $i ${NUM[${i}]} $PERCWRITES $SERVERS &$
        ((i++))
    done
```

Comment: That's not an array. An array would be `num=( 2 2 2 0 )`

Comment: And that's a **really** buggy way to pass arguments to ssh, though addressing the issue would be out-of-scope of the individual question. Basically -- `ssh` munges all its arguments together into a single string, and passes that string for execution by a remote shell. If you want to maintain control over how things are parsed by that remote shell, the proper practice is to build an single `eval`-safe string *locally* and pass it as a single argument.

Comment: BTW, all-caps variable names are used for variables with meaning to the OS and shell -- your own variables should use names with at least one lowercase character to avoid conflicts. See relevant POSIX spec @ http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, reserving lowercase names for application use.

Comment: (When I say "buggy", that includes security bugs -- if you're passing, say, a comment string, a password, a filename, &c. provided by a user as one of your arguments, you don't want any `$(rm -rf ~)` inside that comment to be parsed by the remote shell as code).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't defining an array at all -- you're defining a string.

When an array is accessed as a string, only its first item is returned. That is to say:

```
array=( "first item" "second item" )
echo "$array" ## echos only "first item"
```

When a string is accessed as an array, it acts like a single-element array, with only its first element.

```
string="first item"
echo "${string[0]}" # also echos "first item"
```

If you want to define an array and access it *as an array*, the syntax looks like:

```
array=( "first item" "second item" "third item" )
echo "${array[0]}" # "first item", again.

# iterate over each element in turn
for item in "${array[@]}"; do
  echo "Iterating over array element $item"
done
```

...after which you can either expand to all the items with `"${array[@]}"`, iterate over the indices with `"${!array[@]}"`, or access an individual one with `${array[$idx]}` (where `$idx` is your index number).

Comment: is there also a way to retrieve the data from the string in a similar manner like that? I'd like to receive this string as a command line argument

Comment: You can read it into an array. `read -r -a arrayname <<<"$string"`

Comment: ...that said, that's only a reasonable approach if the restrictions on your array's potential contents are such that you have separator character(s) that can't possibly appear inside the elements themselves. Otherwise, you'll want a separate command-line argument for each element. It's common practice to pass `-n foo -n bar` to specify two array elements, `foo` and `bar`, for instance.

Comment: the array syntax does only work in bash (/bin/bash) not in sh (/bin/sh)

Comment: @KargWare, right; sh _doesn't support arrays at all_. If one wants arrays, it's obligatory to use a shell (like ksh, bash, or zsh) that actually supports arrays.